# Javascript Date: Ensure getMinutes(), getHours(), getSeconds() puts 0 in front if necessary

Tags: javascript, date

Looking for a creative way to be sure values that come from the getHours, getMinutes, and getSeconds() method for the javascript Date object return `"06"` instead of `6` (for example). Are there any parameters that I don't know about? Obviously I could write a function that does it by checking the length and prepending a `"0"` if need be, but I thought there might be something more streamlined than that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Update: ECMAScript 2017 (ECMA-262)

[padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) has been added to pad the beginning of a string with another string, where the first value is the length it should be and the second value being what to pad it with.

For example:

```
let d = new Date()
let h = `${d.getHours()}`.padStart(2, '0')
let m = `${d.getMinutes()}`.padStart(2, '0')
let s = `${d.getSeconds()}`.padStart(2, '0')

let displayDate = h + ":" + m + ":" + s
// Possible Output: 09:01:34
```

---

#### Pre-ECMAScript 2017

As far as I know, there's not. And I do this all the time for converting dates to the XML dateTime format.

It's also important to note that those methods you list return a number, not a string.

You can, of course, add these yourself by modifying `Date.prototype`.

```
Date.prototype.getHoursTwoDigits = function()
{
    var retval = this.getHours();
    if (retval < 10)
    {
        return ("0" + retval.toString());
    }
    else
    {
        return retval.toString();
    }
}

var date = new Date();
date.getHoursTwoDigits();
```

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to delineate the values with something, and quotes were it. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 54):

Similar to @jdmichal's solution, posting because I'd prefer something a little shorter:

```
function pad(n) { return ("0" + n).slice(-2); }

pad(6); // -> "06"
pad(12); // -> "12"
```

Rather than add individual methods to `Date.prototype`, you could just add this method to `Number.prototype`:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function (len) {
    return (new Array(len+1).join("0") + this).slice(-len);
}

// Now .pad() is callable on any number, including those returned by
var time = date.getHours().pad(2) + ":"
         + date.getMinutes().pad(2) + ":"
         + date.getSeconds().pad(2);
```

Comment: You young whipper-snappers and your fancy slicing!

Comment: Awesome! I'm now initializing my input @type="time" element like this:

timeEl.value = ("0"+now.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0"+now.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":00"

Answer (score 14):

```
function pad2(number) {

     return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number

}

document.write(pad2(2) + '<br />');
document.write(pad2(10) + '<br />');
```

OUTPUT:

02

10

Comment: Simple and elegant!  I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so heres my solution

```js
function pad(n) {
  return ((n <= 9 && n >= 0) ? "0":"") + n.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.