# Formatting Javascript string to have 03 not 3?

Tags: javascript, string, format

I have a Javascript that opens today file in html.

```
function openToday()
{   
    var today = new Date();
    var strYear = today.getFullYear();
    var strMonth = today.getMonth();
    var strDay = today.getDate();

    var strURL = "file:/time/"+strYear+"/"+strMonth+"/" + strYear+"_"+strMonth+"_"+strDay+ "/" + strYear+"_"+strMonth+"_"+strDay+".html";

    alert(strURL);
    window.open(strURL,"myWindow");
}
```

The problem is that I want to have the `2011_03_10`, but the code gives me `2011_3_10`.
How can I format the Javascript string to have 03 not 3?

### EDIT

This code works fine

```
function openToday()
{   
    var today = new Date();
    var strYear = today.getFullYear();
    var strMonth = today.getMonth();
    strMonth += 1;
    if(strMonth < 10){
        strMonth = "0" + strMonth;
    }
    var strDay = today.getDate();
    if(strDay < 10){
        strDay = "0" + strDay;
    }

    var strURL = "file:/time/"+strYear+"/"+strMonth+"/" + strYear+"_"+strMonth+"_"+strDay+ "/" + strYear+"_"+strMonth+"_"+strDay+".html";

    window.open(strURL,"myWindow");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Date: Ensure getMinutes(), getHours(), getSeconds() puts 0 in front if necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313875/javascript-date-ensure-getminutes-gethours-getseconds-puts-0-in-front-if)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if the month is only 1 character long (or alternatively, < 9).  Then prepend the 0!

**By length**

```
var strMonth = today.getMonth();

if(strMonth .length == 1){
    strMonth = "0" + strMonth ;
}
```

**By number**

```
var strMonth = today.getMonth();

if(strMonth< 10){
    strMonth= "0" + strMonth;
}
```

Probably want to avoid prefixing the variable with `str` as Javascript doesn't explicitly define types, and can confuse the code.  For example, saying `if strMonth < 10` is fine logic wise, but maintainance wise it's confusing to manage.

**Another Way!**

```
var strMonth = "0" + today.getMonth();
strMonth = strMonth.substring(strMonth.length-2, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a general-purpose [padding function](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/pad-number-zeroes-javascript/):

```
function pad(number, length) {
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = '0' + str;
    }
    return str;
}

pad(today.getDay(), 2); // If today was '3', would print '03'
```

Comment: You can extend it to pad with a defined char as well, instead of explicitly setting it to 0

Answer (score 2):

I made a function for that some time ago.

```
var strURL = "file:/time/"+strYear+"/"+convertDateToString(date.getMonth()+1)+"/" +   strYear+"_"+convertDateToString(date.getMonth()+1)+"_"+strDay+ "/" +   strYear+"_"+strMonth+"_"+strDay+".html";
```

The function:

```
/*
Method: convertDateToString
Input: Integer  
Returns: a string from a number and adds a 0 when the number is smaller than 10

Examples: 1 => 01, 8 => 08, 11 => 11
*/ 
function convertDateToString(number){   
  return (number < 10 ) ? 0+number.toString() : number.toString();
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
var strMonth = today.getMonth();
if(strMonth.length == 1){
   strMonth = '0' + strMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may extend it to allow for padding strings like this:

```
function pad(number, length, padWith) {
    padWith = (typeof padWith!=='undefined) ? padWith : '0';
    var str = '' + number;
    while (str.length < length) {
        str = padWith + str;
    }
    return str;
}
```