# javascript dd/m/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript

I have a date in this format `dd/m/yyyy` (if the month is less than 10) that i want to convert to this one `dd/mm/yyyy` no matter what is the value of the month.

thanks.

Comment: So basically 0-pad the month value?

Comment: Do you just mean that you want to add a leading zero to the month if it's only a single digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution if you know the string is in the exact format you've posted:

```
s = s.replace(/\/(\d)\//, '/0$1/');
```

Of course, you may want to check for `d/m/yyyy`, or `d/mm/yyyy`.

Another option, in that case, is:

```
s = s.replace(/\b\d\b/g, '0$&');
```

Again, assuming the date is the whole string, and not partial in it. The pattern reads:

- `\b\d\b` - A digit that is a whole word (wrapped by non-alphanumeric characters or the edge of the string)
- `/g` - Global replace, as we may have two matches.
- `0$&` - Add a zero to the whole match.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = "06/7/2011";

if(date.length == 9) {
    date = date.substring(0,3)+"0"+date.substring(3);
}

alert(date);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sTf68/

This is obviously not a very robust solution, But if it's just a small issue that you need fixed, it will work for this purpose. For more general date formatting, I suggest you use a JavaScript library to do this like [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) or [Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function normalizeDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split('/');
  return (parts[0] < 10 ? '0' : '')
    + parseInt(parts[0]) + '/'
    + (parts[1] < 10 ? '0' : '')
    + parseInt(parts[1]) + '/'
    + parseInt(parts[2]);
}

alert(normalizeDate('2/3/2000')); //alerts "02/03/2000"
alert(normalizeDate('12/11/2000')); //alerts "12/11/2000"
alert(normalizeDate('12/7/2000')); //alerts "12/07/2000"
```

As you can see this function will add a `0` to the first two numbers, not only the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
var month = "00";

if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"12/9/2011".replace( /\/(\d\d?)\//, function( a, month ) {
    return "/" + ( parseInt( month, 10 ) < 10 ? "0" + month : month ) + "/";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjTGh/

Comment: This is probably the fastest solution. I would search for /\d{1-2}\// (one or two digits followed by a slash) and replace that with a two-digit number the way you did

Comment: Oh and use parseInt(number, 10) to treat 09 correctly. parseInt("09") returns 0

Comment: You could just search for `\/\d\/`. No point in matching `\d{2}` and checking its length, and it is in fact wrong if the input is already in the right format (22/01/2012 -> 22/001/2012)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScipt Date API is a bit of a pain. I would .split('/') to get dd, m and yyy. As Strings. Then use parseInteger(x, 10) to make Numbers out of them (the ,10 is needed so that a month 09 is treated as decimal 9 not invalid octal 9). Then you can make a new padded String from there. (Or a new Date() - but beware, day and month are 0-based!).

Unfortunately, if you want to format Date as a String, you need to do the padding yourself. See e.g. [Formatting Javascript string to have 03 not 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261141/formatting-javascript-string-to-have-03-not-3#5261157)