# Add X days to the specified date

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add number of days to today’s date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

I would like to add X days , where X is the number I specified earlier, to the certain date.

Eg. the date is the `29/11/2012` (format: `DD/MM/YYYY`), and I would like to add `5` days to this date so the output should be `03/12/2012`.

**What have I tried:**

```
var days_to_add = 5;
$myyear = 2012;
$mymonth = 11;
$myday = 29;
date = new Date();
date.setFullYear($myyear,$mymonth,$myday);
date.setDate(date.getDate()+(days_to_add-1));
alert(date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear());
```

It is working, but only when the date doesnt pass to the next month of a given date, otherwise, the output is good.

Have you guys any solutions for that?

Comment: The month should be updated automatically.

Comment: @Diodeus Not really - I would like to add certain amount of days to the `specified` date, while that guy would to the current date.

Comment: @dystroy Yea, thats the main problem; it doesnt. I see the `0` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't in the day addition, as the [setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) function increments automatically the  year or month if needed :

> If the parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setDate
>   attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly

But you're not creating your date correctly. Change

```
$myyear = 2012;
$mymonth = 11;
$myday = 29;
date = new Date();
date.setFullYear($myyear,$mymonth,$myday);
```

to

```
$myyear = 2012;
$mymonth = 11;
$myday = 29;
date = new Date($myyear,$mymonth,$myday);
```

The Date constructor takes a month in [0, 11]. If you want 11 to be november and not december, use

```
date = new Date($myyear,$mymonth-1,$myday);
```

And `getMonth` returns an integer in [0, 11], which may have surprised you too. You need to output `date.getMonth()+1` if you want to have the usual date formating :

```
alert(date.getDate()+'/'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getFullYear());
```

If you want to add leading zeros, you could do this :

```
alert(
     (date.getDate()<10 ? "0" : "") + date.getDate()
     +'/'+
     (date.getMonth()<9 ? "0" : "") + (date.getMonth()+1)
     +'/'+
     date.getFullYear() 
);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jMX6j/)

Note that if you have many date manipulations to do, you should consider using a library like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: Not working, see the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x36gc/

Comment: It works. Read updated answer.

Comment: Yes, but why it shows `2013` while the specified month is the November ? It should output the `03/12/2012` shouldnt it?

Comment: 11 isn't november for the Date constructor, it's december...

Comment: Okay. Sorry; its working fine now, but is there a "way" to add leading zeros to the one numbers days or months?

Comment: I edited with an answer to this new question.

Comment: if it helps someone, found that very neat solution to add leading 0 when needed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313875/javascript-date-ensure-getminutes-gethours-getseconds-puts-0-in-front-i#answer-3313953 That's for me the best answer so far !

Answer (score 3):

Something simpler like this ?

```
 var fiveDaysLater = new Date( existingDate.getTime() );
 fiveDaysLater.setDate(fiveDaysLater.getDate() + 5);
```

Comment: And what is the `existingDate` ?

Comment: The link from @Diodeus can help with this                          var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = someDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;

Comment: Just change existingDate instead of someDate :)